# Wordpress Multisite creating a page in a subdomain site redirects to the main site

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

Everytime I am creating a new page on my subdomain site, then I view the page, I am redirected to the page of my main site and the subdomain url is appened in my main site url.

So example. My main site is `http://example.com` and my subdomain site is `http://another.example.com`

When I created a new page at `http://another.example.com` say Sample Page with a slug of `sample-page` , when I view the page, I am redirected to

```
http://example.com/http:/another.example.com/sample-page/
```

What's wrong with this?

Your help would be greatly appeciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the question we need some details but you can try the following link rules for htacccess rewrite rules, if you have apache running on your server

http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

If you have nginx you can have a look at this (no htaccess file you have to add rules in locations.conf or nginx.conf)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

If you need more help,

send me your details I will do it.

Thanks